# Answers which should be comments

Tags: discussion, comment, answers, review

Today in the review queue I stumbled across an "answer" by a new user (1rep) which should be a comment. However, I was asked if it should be "deleted" or not. But it shouldn't be deleted - it should be made into a comment!

What should I do in such circumstances?

Comment: Just flag for "not an answer"

Comment: @JChau I am presuming that that is how these posts toy there in the first place, so I presume that wouldn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flag the answer and mention that it should be a comment. A moderator can then turn it into a comment.

Comment: Okay, that was what I did :-)