# Answer deleted when flagged as "Should be Comment"

Tags: support, comment, flagging, deleted-answers, specific-flag

A new user,
someone whom I introduced the site/community to,
posted an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102688/is-it-possible-to-uniquly-number-faces-of-a-hexagonal-grid-with-consecutive-numb).

It basically said: "I don't know about the overall problem, but for specific example you give, the constraints will fail after 2 more cells, I checked this manually."

So this isn't an answer, it is a comment.
But as a Rep 1 user, he couldn't make a comment,
so I guess he posted it as an answer.

Seeing this, I flagged it as "Not an answer".
[I know moderators can convert answers into comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13849/answers-which-should-be-comments).

I guess in this case, the moderator thought it was best to delete,
or even slipped and pressed the wrong key.

I'm hoping that this can be undone and then converted into a comment.

Comment: The post was deleted by review. When this happens, it is not converted to a comment. There are many times when a moderator leaves a flag for non-mods to handle; this may be one time where non-mods should leave things for the mods to convert to a comment.

Comment: robojohn: can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?
(I assume you undeleted it, thanks I feel it contributes.)

Comment: @robjohn given that there is the specific reason "it is commentary" when voting to delete, and out of general considerations, the idea that the community leaves something to the moderators to handle seems essentially impossible to implement. This issue might be something that one could raise as a general request for improvement though.

Answer (score 4):

The question has three answers which are currently deleted. Two by established users who deleted their own answers, and a [third](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1105048/622) answer which was deleted [from the review queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/336307).

When someone flags something as low quality, or not an answer (possibly someone else, not you) it goes into the review queue and not the moderators, and users can vote to delete or not to keep it. But they can't turn it into a comment. Which is what happened.